# Create or merge dataframs with Complex column structure with and without header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to start my dataframe with 2 columns only including some value without header. then keep some empty rows and start a new dataframe with a different number of columns starting with the header (in the middle of dataframe).

[image: example of one datafram has 2 sets of column startcures]

Comment: That's not possible with a DataFrame. I imagine you're thinking of an excel sheet.

Comment: I am not thinking of Excel. I got 2  dataframes one with just 2 columns and with no header it has information about the report itself and I want to keep it. then I want to merge it with just another dataframe which has 7 headers.